How to implement and pass functions to the assistant? In the asynchronous streaming example from Azure
My problem is passing functions to the assistant, I don't understand how to properly pass their result to the assistant. The results of the sending are visible in the logs, but the assistant receives that he did not receive the result and the function is currently unavailable json {"function_error": "find_and_get_doctors_info", "error": "Function is not available."}
import asyncio
import json
import os
import random

from azure.ai.assistant.management.async_assistant_client import AsyncAssistantClient
from azure.ai.assistant.management.ai_client_factory import AsyncAIClientType
from azure.ai.assistant.management.async_assistant_client_callbacks import AsyncAssistantClientCallbacks
from azure.ai.assistant.management.async_conversation_thread_client import AsyncConversationThreadClient
from azure.ai.assistant.management.async_message import AsyncConversationMessage
from azure.ai.assistant.management.text_message import TextMessage
from services.gpt_service.tools import available_functions, tools_any_b2c  # Import the available functions
from configs.openai.assistant_config import PHRASES
from services import tts_service

conversation_threads = {}

class MyAssistantClientCallbacks(AsyncAssistantClientCallbacks):
    def __init__(self, message_queue):
        self.message_queue = message_queue

    async def handle_message(self, action, message="hello"):
        await self.message_queue.put((action, message))

    async def on_run_update(self, assistant_name, run_identifier, run_status, thread_name, is_first_message=False,
                            message: AsyncConversationMessage = None):
        if run_status == "streaming":
            await self.handle_message("start" if is_first_message else "message", message.text_message.content)
        elif run_status == "completed":
            if message:
                text_message: TextMessage = message.text_message
                if text_message.file_citations:
                    for file_citation in text_message.file_citations:
                        print(
                            f"\nFile citation, file_id: {file_citation.file_id}, file_name: {file_citation.file_name}")

    async def on_function_call_processed(self, assistant_name, run_identifier, function_name, arguments, response):
        await self.handle_message("function", function_name)

        if function_name in available_functions:
            try:
                args = json.loads(arguments)

                func = available_functions[function_name]
                result = await func(**args)

                await self.handle_message("function_result", json.dumps(result))
            except Exception as e:
                error_message = f"Error calling function {function_name}: {str(e)}"
                await self.handle_message("function_error", error_message)
        else:
            await self.handle_message("function_error", f"Unknown function: {function_name}")

async def display_streamed_messages(message_queue, assistant_name):
    while True:
        message_type, message = await message_queue.get()
        if message_type == "start":
            print(f"{assistant_name}: {message}", end="")
        elif message_type == "message":
            print(message, end="", flush=True)
        elif message_type == "function":
            print(f"{assistant_name}: called {message} function.")
        elif message_type == "function_result":
            print(f"Function result: {message}")
        elif message_type == "function_error":
            print(f"Function error: {message}")
        message_queue.task_done()`

`async def gpt_main(user_message, user_id):
    assistant_name = "b2c_camny"`

    try:
        with open(f"configs/azure_config/assistants/{assistant_name}_assistant_config.json", "r") as file:
            config = file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Configuration file for {assistant_name} not found.")
        return

    try:
        message_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        callbacks = MyAssistantClientCallbacks(message_queue)

        assistant_client = await AsyncAssistantClient.from_json(config, callbacks=callbacks,
                                                                api_key=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"])
        ai_client_type = AsyncAIClientType[assistant_client.assistant_config.ai_client_type]

        conversation_thread_client = AsyncConversationThreadClient.get_instance(ai_client_type)

        if user_id in conversation_threads:
            thread_name = conversation_threads[user_id]
            print(f"Reusing existing thread {thread_name} for user {user_id}")
        else:
            thread_name = await conversation_thread_client.create_conversation_thread()
            if not thread_name:
                print(f"Failed to create conversation thread for user {user_id}")
                return
            conversation_threads[user_id] = thread_name
            print(f"Created new thread {thread_name} for user {user_id}")

        await conversation_thread_client.create_conversation_thread_message(user_message, thread_name)

        print(f"Starting to process messages for thread: {thread_name}")
        await assistant_client.process_messages(thread_name=thread_name, stream=True)

        while True:
            try:
                message_type, message = await asyncio.wait_for(message_queue.get(), timeout=60)
                if message_type in ("start", "message"):
                    print(f"Message received: {message}")
                    yield message
                elif message_type == "function_result":
                    print(f"Function result received: {message}")
                    await MyAssistantClientCallbacks.on_function_call_processed()
                    await asyncio.create_task(display_streamed_messages(message_queue, assistant_name))
                elif message_type == "function_error":
                    print(f"Function error received: {message}")
                message_queue.task_done()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print(f"No messages received within the timeout period.")
                break

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        print(f"Finished processing for thread: {thread_name}")


async def handle_message(user_message, user_id):
    async for response in gpt_main(user_message, user_id):
        print(response)

tools:
async def find_and_get_doctors_info(date: str, service: str, city: str) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    print(f"ChatGPT call tool: find_and_get_doctors_info, date: {date}, service: {service}, city: {city}")

    if service == "Cardiologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "12345",
            "full_name": "Dr. Olena Petrova",
            "doctor_type": "Cardiologist",
            "available_time": "10:00-14:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Dermatologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "54321",
            "full_name": "Dr. Mykhaylo Ivanov",
            "doctor_type": "Dermatologist",
            "available_time": "13:00-18:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Dentist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "67890",
            "full_name": "Dr. Sofia Kovalenko",
            "doctor_type": "Dentist",
            "available_time": "09:00-12:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Ophthalmologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "21436",
            "full_name": "Dr. Dmytro Bondarenko",
            "doctor_type": "Ophthalmologist",
            "available_time": "15:00-20:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Pediatrician":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "85274",
            "full_name": "Dr. Anna Sidorenko",
            "doctor_type": "Pediatrician",
            "available_time": "11:00-16:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Neurologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "93715",
            "full_name": "Dr. Andriy Shevchenko",
            "doctor_type": "Neurologist",
            "available_time": "14:00-19:00",
            "clinic_name": "Neuro Clinic",
        }]
    elif service == "Pulmonologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "70192",
            "full_name": "Dr. Iryna Popel",
            "doctor_type": "Pulmonologist",
            "available_time": "12:00-17:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Gastroenterologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "38651",
            "full_name": "Dr. Bohdan Kravchenko",
            "doctor_type": "Gastroenterologist",
            "available_time": "10:30-15:30",
            "clinic_name": "Gastro Clinic",
        }]
    elif service == "Orthopedist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "49573",
            "full_name": "Dr. Yulia Petrova",
            "doctor_type": "Orthopedist",
            "available_time": "08:00-13:00"
        }]
    elif service == "Urologist":
        return [{
            "doctor_id": "01289",
            "full_name": "Dr. Oleksandr Ivanov",
            "doctor_type": "Urologist",
            "available_time": "16:00-21:00"
        }]
    else:
        return [{ "result": "No doctors available for the selected service and date" }]



available_functions = {
    "find_and_get_doctors_info": find_and_get_doctors_info
}

Here is a link to the template 
Description of functions was done in Azure Studio.
I tried to send the results immediately to the asynchronous message queue, but it didn't work either, the assistant doesn't see the results.

I had just stumbled upon the same example and I am struggling to understand how this all comes together.  I was working in the PetTransportation example in the same repo.  I noticed that line 11 in user_functions says that the file is auto-generated.   Are you trying to edit that file?  Do you have any idea how that file is generated?
EDIT: never mind, I see how it comes together.  The sample were created using the configurator, and that process creates the user_functions.
